# How to get the last two items from the stack of a NavigationPath() object

Tags: ios, swiftui, observable, environment, swiftui-navigationpath

I am facing a challenge in SwiftUI and would appreciate some guidance. In my code, I'm working with a **`NavigationPath()`** object and need to obtain the last two items from the stack. Specifically, this operation should occur within a view named **`SomeView`**, which is deep in the navigation stack.

Inside the action closure of a **`Button`** within **`SomeView`**, I want to assign the last two items of the **`navigationControl.path`** to a let constant if they exist.

I've scoured various sources for a solution, but unfortunately, I haven't found one that fits my requirements. It is crucial that the last two items are obtained from the **`navigationControl`** variable retrieved from the environment. While I am aware that these items can be obtained by injecting them into **`SomeView`** during its instantiation at the parent view, this approach is not acceptable in my case.

To provide a comprehensive overview of the project, I've attached relevant code snippets from other files as well.

```
//  SomeView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap to get the last two items in NavigationStack") {
            // Not sure what to write here.
            // It must be something like the following options just to illustrate what is desired:
            // let lastItem = navigationControl.path.last()
            // let lastItem = navigationControl.path[navigationControl.path.count]
            // However, neither of them are defined.
            // Note that only the last item assignemnt is shown here. However, it is desired to get the last two items from path.
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        SomeView()
            .environment(NavigationControl())
    }
}
```

```
//  NavigationControl.swift

import SwiftUI

@Observable class NavigationControl {
    var path = NavigationPath()
}
```

```
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var navigationControl = navigationControl
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationControl.path)
        {
            Button("Navigate") {
                for i in 1..<5 {
                    navigationControl.path.append(i)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Root View")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                SomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        ContentView()
            .environment(NavigationControl())
    }
}
```

```
//  NavigationPathLastElementApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavigationPathLastElementApp: App {
    @State var navigationControl = NavigationControl()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(navigationControl)
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You seem to be only using `Int`s as the elements of your navigation path. If there is only one type of elements in the navigation path, just use an array of that type instead of a `NavigationPath`.

Comment: Could you please provide context regarding the purpose or objective behind the last two items you mentioned? This will help clarify what you are aiming to achieve.

Comment: @Sweeper, I shared this code as a simple example. In my real application, I will be using different and more complex custom types. That's why I have to use a NavigationPath() object and cannot use a simple Int array for the path object.

Comment: @Binshad, if I understood you well, you are asking why I shared the contents of ContentView.swift and NavigationPathLastElementApp.swift. I believe you referred to these files with "last two items". Please correct me if I misunderstood you. I shared those two files to give the full context of the simple project where I showed the problem to which I am seeking a solution.

Comment: If there are different types of things in your navigation path, why would it be useful to get the last 2 elements? You don't even know what type they are.

Comment: @baltacican We have limited functionality with the navigation path. When you tap the button, what are you trying to achieve? If you retrieve the last two items, what do you intend to do with them?

Comment: @Binshad, in SomeView, I will create a new object (let's call myObj). I didn't add this part to the code because it is not directly relevant to the problem of reading the last two elements of the NavigationPath() object. While creating myObj, I will add the last two elements of the path to the two separate properties of myObj. This is why I need the two elements of the path because I will create the new object (myObj) based on the values of the two elements of the path. If I fail to get these two values, I fail to create myObj successfully.

Comment: @baltacican The NavigationPath is useful for keeping track of your navigation history, especially when adding or removing views. But if you need to keep track of specific objects within certain views, you'll have to manage that separately.

Comment: @baltacican I have made some modifications to your code. Please check if they are useful for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get even one item from NavigationPath, and you want as many as two. This is a dead end – consider alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationPath is a useful tool for handling the order of screens or views in a navigation stack. It helps you keep track of which screen is currently being displayed and manage the navigation flow within your app.

I have made some changes to your code to display views with data passing using navigation paths. Please use this if it solves your problem.

```
@Observable class NavigationControl {
    var path = NavigationPath()
}
```

---

```
@main
struct NavigationPathLastElementApp: App {
    @State var navigationControl = NavigationControl()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(navigationControl)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var navigationControl = navigationControl
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationControl.path)
        {
            SomeView()
            .navigationTitle("Root View")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { int in
                SomeView1(number: int)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
                SomeView2(string: string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("SomeView 1") {
            navigationControl.path.append(10)
        }
        
        Button("SomeView 2") {
            navigationControl.path.append("hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct SomeView1: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    var number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap") {
            print(number)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct SomeView2: View {
    @Environment(NavigationControl.self) private var navigationControl: NavigationControl
    var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap") {
            print(string)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your modifications. This could be a workaround for my application.